# ¿Como compilar un plugin que esta un formato jar a la versión de java instalada en la maquina?

Tags: java, eclipse

Me gustaría saber como compilar un plugin por ejemplo org.pm.contract_1.0.0.jar que está la versión de java 1.8 0 1.7 a versiones de java superiores. Es decir actualmente tengo instalado java 11 y me gustaria saber como puedo compilar ese plugin y que soporte java 11. Adicional a esto estoy usando el IDE eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde sé, no es posible actualizar un `jar` compilado con una versión de java a una versión posterior sin recompilar desde los fuentes.

Pero, por lo general las `jvm` pueden correr código compilado con versiones anteriores a la actual instalada.

Si tenés un problema puntual de compatibilidad, las opciones son conseguir un jar actualizado (de maven por ejemplo), o de contar con los fuentes (y sus dependencias), hacer las modificaciones correspondientes en el código y compilar un nuevo jar.